# Can't switch to TTY / virtual console on Mac Book Pro, 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, tty

Running Ubuntu 14.04 on a 2008 MBP (3,1). Dual booting with rEFInd.

Pressing `CTRL+ALT+F#` does nothing at the greeter or once logged in.

I have `nomodeset` in grub, if I remove it I can't get ubuntu to boot (screen goes black during boot and never recovers).

I am using the nouveau video drivers. I have previously tried mucking around trying to get various nvidia drivers to work but it was never successful.

I am not AMAZING with ubuntu, but I am somewhat capable and learning fast so I'm eager to try and fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up being able to resolve this with the help of `xinput` and figuring out that the keys were working, I just needed to be holding down the `fn` key.